# How to store array in javascript using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model

I am new using js , I had function to store object in array to Angular model,
for example :

```
function getSpec(){
    debugger
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<main.specifications.length;i++){
        main.newProduct.Specification= ("{\""+main.specifications[i].key+"\":\""+main.specifications[i].value+"\"}");

    }
}
```

`main.newProduct.Specification` is a model, and I want to store key and value according to array length.
and I want to store to db like: `{"Ram":"1GB","Color":"BLACK"}`

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If  `main.newProduct.Specification` is object then you can create key value pair using  `main.newProduct.Specification[main.specifications[i].key] = main.specifications[i].value;`

```
function getSpec(){
        debugger
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<main.specifications.length;i++){
        var temp = {};
        temp[main.specifications[i].key]=main.specifications[i].value;                  
        main.newProduct.Specification.push(temp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi , Thanks for feedback, i think it missunderstanding, i mean i can display the value of key and the value of value .. but if i put it inside for, its only display one on one , but i want display all the value in array length , if i had length= 4 then i want to display all of them in one display, can it?

Comment: i modified answer. may i know how you are showing in UI?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `getSpec()` as follows:

```
function getSpec(){
  debugger
  var i;
  main.newProduct.Specification = main.newProduct.Specification || {}; // This is optional, and is just a fallback

  for(i = 0; i < main.specifications.length; i++) {
    main.newProduct.Specification[main.specifications[i].key] = main.specifications[i].value;
  }
}
```

The above initializes `main.newProduct.Specification` with an empty object if it is not already initialized and appends all the properties to it.

**Update**:

The above can also be reduced to this:

```
function getSpec() {
  main.newProduct.Specification = main.specifications.reduce(function(obj, item) {
    obj[item.key] = item.value;
    return obj; 
  }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution using ES6 [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop :**

```js
let mainObj = {
  "specifications" : [
    { "key":"Ram", "value":"1GB" },
    { "key":"Color", "value":"BLACK" }
  ]
};

mainObj.newProduct = {
 "specifications" : {}
}
for (let i of mainObj.specifications) {
  mainObj.newProduct.specifications[i.key] = i.value;
}

console.log(mainObj.newProduct.specifications);
```